# BroadcastReceiver receives events with delay after reboot

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I try to receive PHONE_STATE intents with next BroadcastReceiver

```
<receiver android:name=".CallReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

But after rebooting my Nexus 5X and making the call to this device, ringing events can be received after the call has been already finished a minute ago.
How can I fix it? Any ideas?

Comment: use priority in intent-filter like <intent-filter android:priority="999"> and check below link for more detail. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html#priority

Comment: On what API level are you?

Comment: How do you register the broadcast receiver? Only implicitely?

Comment: @rds API = 26, only implicetely

Answer (score 2):

this because there any other Receiver listen to this broadcast, you can try to improve you Recevier' priority just like that

```
<intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">  
<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />  
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43988744/5996106)-

There are many, many apps that want to get control at boot time. How quickly yours will get its turn will depend on many variables, such as the number of installed apps, the CPU speed of the device, the amount of system RAM on the device, etc.

Also, starting an activity from a BroadcastReceiver at boot time is fairly evil. If you want to be the first thing the user sees after a reboot, write a home screen implementation.

All you can do is give priority like this -

```
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" android:priority="999"/>
```

Comment: priority is for ordered broadcasts i do not think the `boot_completed` is ordered broadcast

Comment: android:priority is inline with the <intent-filter tag under <receiver (for broadcast receivers)

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking when you create Intent for send Broadcast, you miss set flag for intent. You need set tag **FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND** for your intent.

I don't see source code create Intent to sent Broadcast in this topic so I suggest a sample:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(...);
intent.setFlags(FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND);
...
```

You can see more at: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND

**EDIT:**

I has just changed file AndroidManifest, you can try it:

```
<receiver android:name=".CallReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: I didn't send any broadcasts, I have just received it

Comment: @shmakova: I just updated answer, you can try again.

Comment: The problem was PHONE_STATE broadcast, RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED works well

Answer (score 1):

You can use foreground service and register your receiver in your foreground service instead of manifest. Using a foreground service may reduce delay as foreground service is more important than background service and registered receiver in a foreground service may be more important to OS than registered receiver in manifest as always your program is running and in foreground before phone state is changed.

Also  i do not think `ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED` is an Ordered Broadcast as it could not be aborted by receiver thus using Priority which other answers suggest has no effect on it (**priority is only for ordered broadcasts**).

**remove phone state receiver from manifest but keep your BOOT_COMPLETED receiver in manifest and start following service at boot complete**

register receiver in onCreate of a Service:

```
   @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        phoneStateReceiver = new PhoneStateReceiver();
        registerReceiver(phoneStateReceiver, new IntentFilter(TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED));
    }
```

unregister in onDestroy:

```
   @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        unregisterReceiver(phoneStateReceiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

add a static method to your service to start service:

```
// start service even if your app is in stopped condition in android 8+
static void requestStart(@NonNull final Context context, @NonNull final String action){
        final Context appContext = context.getApplicationContext();
        Intent intent = new Intent(appContext, AppService.class);
        intent.setAction(action);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            // this is required to start the service if there is 
            // no foreground process in your app and your app is
            // stopped in android 8 or above
            appContext.startForegroundService(intent);
        } else {
            appContext.startService(intent);
        }
    }
```

start foreground in your `onStartCommand`

```
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
         if(ACTION_START.equals(intent.getAction()))
           startForeground(ID, notification);
         else if(ACTION_STOP.equals(intent.getAction()))
           stopForeground(true);

         return START_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: As mentioned here: https://issuetracker.google.com/37273064#comment4, ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED (android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE) will be whitelisted for the Android O release. Though they may be replaced with a different mechanism in a future release.

Comment: Question was about delay after reboot, not about why it doesn't work on Android O

Comment: @shmakova it may also solve delay as your service is in foreground and more important to OS than background service or even a stopped app state

Comment: @shmakova i do not think PHONE_STATE is an Ordered Broadcast as it could not be aborted thus using `Priority` which other answers suggest has no effect on it

Comment: @shmakova also setting flag in intent has no mean because you are not the one who sends intent for phone state it is the phone app which notifies you about phone state and you just receive that intent

Comment: Change your answer and write there about ordered broadcasts

Answer (score 0):

The value must be greater than -1000 and less than 1000. please,go through below link

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html

Answer (score 0):

`ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED` doesn't have the `FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND` flag, hence it runs in the background queue.

*Hypothesis*: On startup, there are often many applications which are listening to `BOOT_COMPLETED` (yes, that's a bad practice, but some people still do it, you should blame them) and as a result the background queue is quite busy. I'm not surprise that another background broadcast added in a busy queue takes a minute to be handled

You can confirm my hypothesis by looking in logcat for

> ActivityManager: processNextBroadcast

As an alternative, you could [register a listener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html#addTriggerContentUri(android.app.job.JobInfo.TriggerContentUri)) on the [phone log content provider.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html)

Comment: How can it take a minute to broadcast. Nexus 5X have good configuration, Max it should take 10 seconds. Can you explain in details or provide any link. Thanks!!!

Comment: What timestamps do you observe in the logcat?