# After device restart, my app receiving BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast slower/later than other apps?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, bootcompleted

When I restart my device, I am receiving `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast much slower (around 10-15 seconds later) than other apps.

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43988566/broadcastreceiver-for-boot-completed-is-too-slow). But I do not think this is completely true. How (I think) I proved it wrong:

(Let's define X as an application that receives `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast faster than mine).

1. Installed X
2. Installed my application.
3. Restarted device.

RESULT: X received `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast very fast. My applicated received the broadcast slow.

4. Uninstalled both applications.
5. Installed my application once again.
6. Restarted device.

RESULT: My app received `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast slow again.

7. Uninstalled my application.
8. Installed X.
9. Restarted device.

RESULT: X received `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast very fast once again.

**CONCLUSION:  My app receives `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast slow whether X is installed or not. X always receives `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast very fast.** *How X is being able to receive the boot completed broadcast much faster than my application even though X is installed after my application?*

That is why I  do not think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43988566/broadcastreceiver-for-boot-completed-is-too-slow?noredirect=1&lq=1) is completely true answer. There is something X is doing that causing it to receive `BOOT_COMPLETED` at a higher priority than my app.

Maybe there are some other broadcasts other than `BOOT_COMPLETED` which are much faster?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
...
<receiver 
    android:name=".receivers.BootCompletedIntentReceived">
    <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
        <!--For HTC devices-->
        <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

BootCompletedIntentReceived.kt

```
class BootCompletedIntentReceived: BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        //DO SOMETHING HERE
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of priority of intent-filter must be between -1000 and 1000.
Try this:

```
<intent-filter android:priority="999">
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the app X is a priveledged application.
From the documentation for **android:priority** attribute:

> In certain circumstances the requested priority is ignored and the
> value is capped to 0. This occurs when: A non-privileged application
> requests any priority >0

So if X is a priveledged app and it requests a high priority, it will be granted, and your app, being non-priveledged, will always get the broadcast later.

Answer (score 0):

## Experiment

I created 2 sample apps - **app1** and **app2**, each of which registered its own `BroadcastReceiver` for receiving an `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`. So, `BroadcastReceiver` for **app1** had a priority of `10` and the other - `20`.

### app1

```
...
    <receiver
        android:name="com.example.app1.BootCompletedIntentReceiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="10">
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
...
```

### app2

```
...
    <receiver
        android:name="com.example.app2.BootCompletedIntentReceiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="20">
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
...
```

### Result

> 2021-03-30 18:14:07.337 3453-3453/com.example.app1 E/Anatolii: BootCompletedIntentReceiver called
>
> 2021-03-30 18:14:07.509
> 3498-3498/com.example.app2 E/Anatolii: BootCompletedIntentReceiver
> called

As it can be seen from the output, **app1** received the intent earlier, event though it had a higher priority.

## Answer

Your `android:priority` doesn't matter because `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` is probably not sent in the synchronous way, and so priority is ignored as stated in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html):

> `android:priority`
> ...
> It controls the order in which broadcast receivers are executed to
> receive broadcast messages. Those with higher priority values are
> called before those with lower values. (The order applies only to
> synchronous messages; it's ignored for asynchronous messages.)...